# triple tier drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to make a menu that has 3 tiers, for example i want to hover over 'family' and be shown 'holidays' and 'day Trips'. Then I want to hover 'holidays' or 'day trips' and be shown the next options 'videos 1-3'. I have only been doing HTML5 and CSS3 for a few weeks so I am quite green. Any help would be great.

```
<ul id="menu2">
                <li> <a href="#">Family</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu2">
                        <li><a href="#">Holidays</a>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Video 1 </a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Video 2 </a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Video 3 </a></li>
                         </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Day Trips</a>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Video 1 </a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Video 2 </a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Video 3 </a></li>
                         </li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
            </ul>
```

CSS

```
#menu2, ul#menu2 ul.sub-menu2 {
padding:0;
margin-top: -41px;  
}

#menu2 li, ul#menu2 ul.sub-menu2 li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
width:100px;
left:73%;
margin-bottom:4px;
}
#menu2 li a, ul#menu2 li ul.sub-menu2 li a {
text-decoration: none;
text-align:center;
color: yellow;
background: black;
padding: 5px;
display:inline-block;
width:100px;
border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border: 2px solid yellow;
}
#menu2 li {
position: relative;
}

#menu2 li ul.sub-menu2 {
display:none;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
right: 72px;
width: auto;
margin-top:6px;
margin-bottom:-2px;
}
#menu2 li:hover ul.sub-menu2 {
display:block;  
}


#menu2 li ul.sub-menu2 a:hover {
background-color: yellow;
color: black;
}
```

Comment: What is the specific issue you're running into? What have you tried so far to fix it? Can you set up a jsfiddle showcasing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is not correct. It should be like this:

```
<ul id="menu2">
    <li><a href="#">Family</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu2">
            <li><a href="#">Holidays</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Video 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Video 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Video 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Day Trips</a>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Video 1 </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Video 2 </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Video 3 </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And you have to modify your CSS a little bit. I made a little dummy here:

[generic DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eBLh7/)